# Android, reload or refresh current fragment after click "ok" in DIALOG

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

This is my dialog inside fragment it works fine, now I want that when i click "ok" button it reload the current fragment. the dialog is show when the method showDialog is called:
mi fragment is  android.support.v4.app.Fragment

```
void showDialog() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_agenda, null);
    TextView txtNombre = (TextView)promptView.findViewById(R.id.txtdialog1);
    txtNombre.setText("ADD THIS STUFF?");
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            sendSomeStuff();
            //HERE TODO RELOAD OR REFRESH THE FRAGMENT


        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        } });
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

**update**
this is the fragment. Iwant to recall the onCreateView methos of the fragment

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
//...some variables
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    showDialog()//HERE I CALL MY CUSTOM DIALOG

    return rootView;
}
}
```

**The Simple Solution**

Tested using viewpager, and FragmentPagerAdapter

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

ft.detach(FragmentOne.this).attach(FragmentOne.this).commit();
```

Comment: can we also have the two .xml files pls? Do you have a SwipeRefreshLayout on your Fragment?

Comment: please explain how excatly you want to reload the fragment. If you want to fully recreate the fragment (which is not recomended) you can make the fragment transaction again with same view and new fragment instance. If you just want to update fragments contents you can just update your views depending on your fragment's state

Comment: I want to recrreate the view or recall the onCreateView method of the fragment

Comment: @GV_FiQst I add the fragment code

Comment: Sorry, but your logic is complex, and not recommended. Please reconsider what you are trying to do. What is your actual issue? Perhaps a simpler solution can be applied

Comment: Is complex? to refresh the fragment form a dialog when click "ok"? there are some  autocompletetetview adapter that are filled with information of external server. after click ok button from dialog, the adapter must be rebuilt because the json will not be the same

Answer (score 1):

refresh fragment when fragment is visible to user

```
    override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
    if(isVisibleToUser){
        if (getFragmentManager() != null) {
            getFragmentManager()
                ?.beginTransaction()
                ?.detach(this)
                ?.attach(this)
                ?.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getFragmentManager() is deprecated

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment

Answer (score 0):

There is no standart way to recreate the fragment. Fragment has no `recreate()` method like Activity has. Unlike Activities, instances of which are created by system, fragments are created by developer (means you). So you have two ways:

**Way #1 Recreate the fragment instance (Not recommended)**

If you want to have onCreateView() method being called again you can run the same transaction again to recreate the fragment instance:

```
FragmentOne fg = new FragmentOne();
fg.setArguments(yourArgsBundle);

getFragmentManager()  // or getSupportFragmentManager() if your fragment is part of support library
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.yourRootView, fg)
        .commit();
```

This way is not recommended because this will cause your content view to be reinflated, and view-tree to be rebuilt again.

**Way #2 Update the current fragment instance**

Much simpler and more recommended way is to simply update your view depending on your new json:

If it's a`TextView` where the text was changed call `myTextView.setText("new data");` again. If it's an`ImageView` where source image was changed call `myImageView.setImageBitmap(myNewBitmap)` again.

You have initialized your view depending on your json once for sure. So just do this again with new json.

P.S. don't use `onCreateView()` method in initialization purposes. Better use `onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedState)` method in these purposes.